# VBA- A Timer Function, with Step by Step Capturing the elapsed times

Tags: excel, function, timer, vba

I was looking for a timer function that easily can be embedded in my coeds to show me how many seconds each step is taking. I am doing this with a regular debug.print and several variables which made my code busy and also hard to do subtracting new timer from last recorded step was redundant as well. I am looking for a function to capture the time takes for each step and also finding out the total elapsed time from the first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I developed for that purpose. You have to declare a public object of "Scripting.Dictionary" type and also a long variable as ti.

## Late Binding:

```
Public d As Object, ti as long
```

and in one you your procedures, prior to calling the function:

```
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

## Early Binding

You can use early binding if you have Microsoft Scripting Runtime already added to your library. Your declaration would be like below:

```
Dim d As New Scripting.Dictionary, ti as long
```

anyway here is the:

## Function

Title is a string as a reminder or tag of the stage/step in the code.
  Newstart should set TRUE, for the first instance of the function.
  NeedTotal should set true if you want total elapsed time up until that stage.

```
Public Function gettimer(Optional ByVal Title As String, _
                     Optional ByVal Newstart As Boolean, _
                     Optional ByVal NeedTotal As Boolean)
If Newstart = True Or ti = 0 Then
    ti = 0
    d("T0") = Timer
    gettimer = ti & vbTab & vbTab & "0.00" & vbTab & vbTab & "Start @ " _
    & Format(Time, "h:mm:ss") & vbTab & Title
Else
    gettimer = ti & vbTab & vbTab & Format(Round(Timer - d("T" & ti - 1), 2), "0.00") _
    & vbTab & vbTab & Title
    d("T" & ti) = Timer
End If
If NeedTotal Then
    gettimer = gettimer & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Time elapsed from the start = " _
    & vbTab & Round(d("T" & ti) - d("T0"), 4)
End If
ti = ti + 1
Debug.Print gettimer
End Function
```

Comment: You might be interested in [MicroTimer function](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=1068). It is often used to profile vba code with high accuracy.

Comment: Hi, I know about that. But my need was above one.  Easily give me the time in steps...